# Launching a new window and filling form values using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have been learning JavaScript and i am attempting to launch a new window on click after a user has placed info into a form fields and then placing that info into form fields in the newly launched window. I have read many posts and methods in Stackoverflow however i cant seem to get it to work properly.

Starting page HTML:

```
<form id="memCat" methed="get" class="member_catalogue">
     <button type="submit" class="prodBtn" id="catOrder" onclick="openMemberOrder()"><img class="prodImg" src="../../../Images/bcpot002_thumb.jpg" name="Red Bowl"></button>
      <div class="cat_block">
            <label class="cat_label" for="cat_name">Product Name:</label>
            <input class="cat_input" type="text" id="catID" value="bepot002" readonly>
       </div>
       <div class="cat_block">
             <label class="cat_label" for="cat_description">Product Description:</label>
             <input class="cat_input" type="text" id="catDesc" value="Ocre Red Pot" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="cat_block">
               <label class="cat_label" for="cat_price">Per unit price:$</label>
               <input class="cat_input" type="number" id="catVal" value="10" readonly>
        </div>
 </form>
```

New page HTML:

```
<form id="memOrder" method="post">
      <div>
           <label for="pname">Product Name:</label>
           <input type="text" id="orderID" readonly>
      </div>
      <div>
           <label for="pdescription">Product Description:</label>
           <input type="text" id="orderDesc" readonly>
      </div>
      <div>
            <label for="quantity">Quantity ordered:</label>
            <input type="number" class="quantOrder" id="orderOrder" value="1" min="1" max="10">
      </div>
      <div>
            <label for="ind_price">Per unit price: $</label>
            <input type="number" class="quantCount" id="orderVal" readonly>
      </div>
      <div>
            <label for="tot_price">Total Price: $</label>
            <input type="number" class="quantCount" id="orderTotal" readonly>
      </div>
      <div>
            <button type="reset">Clear Order</button>
            <button type="submit" id="orderCalc">Calculate Total</button>
            <button type="submit" id="orderPlace">Place Order</button>
      </div>
</form>
```

Script i have to date:

```
function openMemberOrder() {
    document.getElementById("orderID").value = document.getElementById("catID").document.getElementsByTagName("value");
    document.getElementById("orderDesc").value = document.getElementById("catDesc").document.getElementsByTagName("value");
    document.getElementById("orderVal").value = document.getElementById("catVal").document.getElementsByTagName("value");
    memberOrderWindow = window.open('Member_Orders/members_order.html','_blank','width=1000,height=1000');
};
```

script and other meta tags in head are correct as other code is working correctly.

Comment: what about storing your data to local storage localStorage.setItem('name','Kai'); and get it back on next form, would that work for your solution.?

Comment: @Kai sounds like it could, as i am learning this all from scratch im not sure how to build the query though..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much trial and error i have had success with this:

On the submission page:
 1. I created a button on the page that will capture the input form data
 2. i created the localstorage function in JS
 3. I then placed the script tag at the bottom of the page before the closing body tag

```
HTML
<button type="submit" class="prodBtn" id="catOrder" onclick="openMemberOrder()"><img class="prodImg" src="../../../Images/bcpot002/bcpot002_thumb.jpg" name="Red Bowl"></button>

Javascript
var catID = document.getElementById("catID").value;
var catDesc = document.getElementById("catDesc").value;
var catVal = document.getElementById("catVal").value;

function openMemberOrder() {
    var memberOrderWindow;
    localStorage.setItem("catID", document.getElementById("catID").value);
    localStorage.setItem("catDesc", document.getElementById("catDesc").value);
    localStorage.setItem("catVal", document.getElementById("catVal").value);
    memberOrderWindow = window.open('Member_Orders/members_order.html', '_blank', 'width=1240px,height=1050px,toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no');
} ;

Script Tag
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../JS/catOrder.js"></script>
```

I then created the new page with the following javascript in the header loading both an image grid as well as input element values:

```
var urlArray = [];
var urlStart = '<img src=\'../../../../Images/';
var urlMid = '_r';
var urlEnd = '.jpg\'>';
var ID = localStorage.getItem('catID');

    for (var rowN=1; rowN<5; rowN++) {
        for (var colN = 1; colN < 6; colN++){
            urlArray.push(urlStart + ID + '/' + ID + urlMid + rowN + '_c' + colN + urlEnd)
        }
    }

window.onload = function urlLoad(){
        document.getElementById('gridContainer').innerHTML = urlArray;   
        document.getElementById('orderID').setAttribute('value', localStorage.getItem('catID'));
        document.getElementById('orderDesc').setAttribute('value', localStorage.getItem('catDesc'));
        document.getElementById('orderVal').setAttribute('value', localStorage.getItem('catVal'));
        };
```

I then created 2 buttons to calculate a total based on inputs and clearing values separately, the script for this was placed at the bottom of the page.

```
function total() {
        var Quantity = document.getElementById('orderQuant').value;
        var Value = document.getElementById('orderVal').value;
        var Total = Quantity * Value;
        document.getElementById('orderTotal').value = Total;
    }

function clearForm() {
        var i = 0;
        var j = 0;
        document.getElementById('orderQuant').value = i;    
        document.getElementById('orderTotal').value = j;  
    }
```